# Downloading mongoDB error

Tags: server, gnome-terminal, database, mongodb, ubuntu-tweak

Last month downloaded mongoDB onto my Ubuntu 20.04 using `sudo apt install mongodb-org` I found the package, installed it and mongodb was working fine. I however deleted it and when I try reinstalling it the same command outputs "Cannot locate file mongodb-org".
`sudo apt install mongodb` works but `sudo systemctl start mongod.service` outputs "Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found". How do I solve this?
I once set my ubuntu software to download from Main server, but it was originally downloading from my local home country server, which I changed the setting back to. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct service name is `mongodb.service`.

You may check using:

```
dpkg -L mongodb-server
```